Why did Rambam say that only nine parah adumah offerings ever took place?
In Mishneh Torah Parah Adumah 3, the Rambam says that only nine red heifers have ever been offered, including the pre-Temple period, the First Temple period, and the Second Temple Period.
As I understand it, for someone to be purified and go to the Temple, a red heifer offering must be performed, and most men were obligated to go to the Temple during pilgrimage festivals (Mishna Chagiga 1:1).
Were people back then just very careful not to go near corpses?
What about Chevra Kadishas? Were they just exempt?

Prof. Zohar Amar and others conducted experiments a few years ago on burning cows and creating water-ash mixtures and published their results in a series of essays. Their conclusions were that one cow properly halachically burned could create enough water-ash mixtures to last millions of people many years. So the small number of cows shouldn't surprise us (not to mention that people in the diaspora usually didn't make aliyah la'regel every year).

Furthermore, we have a lot of textual and archeological evidence that shows that from the time of the Chashmonaim and onward, even past the destruction, it became very very commonplace (the norm, really) to be careful about purity.

Interestingly, we also have some sources that show that the last remaining ashes were preserved well into the period of the tannaim until I believed they were being delivered over a body of water and sunk.

They diluted it a lot

@Harel13 (third comment): are you referring to the story in Chagigah 23a where they were carrying parah adumah water in a riverboat? In that case it didn't sink, just became tamei.

@Meir maybe, it's been awhile since I last looked at all of the sources. If so, thanks for the correction.

Rambam is referring to Mishna Parah 3:5:

לֹא מָצְאוּ מִשֶּׁבַע, עוֹשִׂין מִשֵּׁשׁ, מֵחָמֵשׁ, מֵאַרְבַּע, מִשָּׁלשׁ, מִשְּׁתַּיִם וּמֵאֶחָת. וּמִי עֲשָׂאָם. הָרִאשׁוֹנָה עָשָׂה משֶׁה, וְהַשְּׁנִיָּה עָשָׂה עֶזְרָא, וְחָמֵשׁ, מֵעֶזְרָא וָאֵילָךְ, דִּבְרֵי רַבִּי מֵאִיר. וַחֲכָמִים אוֹמְרִים, שֶׁבַע מֵעֶזְרָא וָאֵילָךְ. וּמִי עֲשָׂאָן. שִׁמְעוֹן הַצַּדִּיק וְיוֹחָנָן כֹּהֵן גָּדוֹל עָשׂוּ שְׁתַּיִם שְׁתַּיִם, אֶלְיְהוֹעֵינַי בֶּן הַקּוֹף וַחֲנַמְאֵל הַמִּצְרִי וְיִשְׁמָעֵאל בֶּן פִּיאָבִי עָשׂוּ אַחַת אֶחָת:
If they did not find the residue of the ashes of the seven [red cows] they performed the sprinkling with those of six, of five, of four, of three, of two or of one. And who prepared these? Moses prepared the first, Ezra prepared the second, and five were prepared from the time of Ezra, the words of Rabbi Meir. But the sages say: seven from the time of Ezra. And who prepared them? Shimon the Just and Yohanan the high priest prepared two each; Elihoenai the son of Ha-Kof and Hanamel the Egyptian and Ishmael the son of Piabi prepared one each.

The text of the Mishna implies that on many occasions they had leftover ashes from several cows available.

So a new offering didn't have to take place each time, they re-used the leftover residue of previous offerings?

@MosheDavid It seems most of the time they had residue of ash from several cows.

@MosheDavid Each time, they would use the leftover ashes (and, ideally, a mixture of the leftovers from all the previous ones) to sprinkle on the Kohen who would be preparing the new one.
